# Do any published adventures contain spells a wizard can copy that aren't written in a spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, published-adventures, wizard, spellcasting

A wizard can copy a spell they find into their spellbook. This is described in the "Your Spellbook" section of the Wizard's class features:

> When you find a wizard spell of 1st level or higher, you can add it to your spellbook if it is of a spell level you can prepare and if you can spare the time to decipher and copy it.

Notably, it does not say "when you find a wizard spell *in a spellbook*". Are there any instances in published adventures where a wizard can copy a spell from something other than a spellbook?

I'm obviously not concerned about spell scrolls here. I'm looking for something like a spell written on a wall or stone tablet, or other surface *that does not require a check like a spell scroll does*.

[This Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79611/62294) firmly establishes that the wizard can copy their spells *from any written source*, but I am not aware of any published examples of this outside of found spellbooks.

Comment: Why are you asking? This seems like a weird thing to care about for the pure mechanics of it, which suggests that there is some underlying thing you;re trying to address.

Comment: @fectin I was hoping there was a context where Wizards had implemented this themselves to inform my own implementation of this in my games.

Comment: Related on [Does a Wizard's spellbook need to be a book?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131177/does-a-wizards-spellbook-need-to-be-a-book)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**There are a few examples.**

### From *Storm King's Thunder*

There is a specific room in one of the major locations which has the following:

> Chapter 10 says, in [Room 25 - Library](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/skt/hold-of-the-storm-giants#25Library) (p. 212):

> Five rocks have the following wizard spells inscribed on them: *antimagic field*, *conjure elemental*, *fabricate*, *legend lore*, and *stone shape*. The rocks function like pages of a spellbook, but each weighs 600 pounds. A character who has a spellbook can record these spells in it.

These are not spellbooks, but can provide spells for wizards to copy.

**...and there are a few books that aren't strictly spellbooks but do contain wizard spells:**

### From *Out of the Abyss*

In one of the major locations, an important NPC has the following item:

> Chapter 4 says, in the Treasure section under ["Finding Droki"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/oota/gracklstugh#FindingDroki) (p. 69):

> Pages of lizard-skin parchment held together between two leather covers from two different books. The pages are full of mad scribbles and arcane formulas, but a character proficient in Intelligence (Arcana) can study them for 1 hour to discover that they constitute a spellbook containing the *Tenser’s floating disk* and *feign death* spells.

This is not quite a typical spellbook but provides a couple spells in a manner similar to one.

### From *Icewind Dale: Rime of the Frostmaiden*

There is a book found in a major location:

> Chapter 5, in [Room G22 - Chamber of the Codicil](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/idrotf/aurils-abode#G22ChamberoftheCodicil), contains [*The Codicil of White*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/the-codicil-of-white), a magic book whose description appears in ["Appendix D: Magic"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/idrotf/appendix-d-magic#TheCodicilofWhite) (p. 317):

> The codicil was written by followers of Auril as a primer on her worship. The first page is a title page with the snowflake symbol of Auril on it. The remaining pages describe various priestly rituals and ceremonies in chilling detail. Nestled among these descriptions is a spell that wizards can learn ([*frost fingers*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/frost-fingers), described later in this appendix) [...]

While it is a book, it is explicitly not a spellbook, simply containing a spell that wizards can transcribe.

### From Dungeon of The Mad Mage

In addition to those above, there is a stone statue with a stone likeness of a spellbook that a spell can be copied from:

> On level 7, in the courtyard of **Maddgoth's Castle** (p. 102)

> **Statue**. In the center of this open-air courtyard, surrounded by gardens of glittering, pebble-sized crystals, stands a 9-foot-tall statue of a plump human wizard (...) reading from a spellbook. (...)
>  Carved into the pages of its open spellbook is the *Mordenkainen's Sword* spell. A wizard can take a rubbing of the spell and copy it into a spellbook.

Comment: I think you've squeaked by on a technicality with the first one. I said no spell books, and that's two halves of different spellbooks, which is not technically a spellbook. The example from *SKT* is exactly what Im looking for.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I always read the Out of the Abyss example as counting a spellbook for copying purposes only. The NPC is not a spellcaster, so I figured it was just random mystic scribblings, but I suppose it could be considered a spellbook as well.

Comment: The example from *ID:RotF* blurs the lines here a bit. Granted, I asked for no spellbooks, and this is a liturgy book with spells in it. Close enough, definitely helps.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I reorganized in an attempt to bring it more in line with what you are looking for (separating the books from the rocks in this case)